# Angular4/MEAN does not render data on the template

Tags: angular

I am learning MEAN stack with Angular4 and got stuck up with a problem.I use a service to get the data from the node.js and it is subscribed by app.component.
Logging the result displays  the right output however, on rendering it on the template doesn't works.There is no warnings or any other errors but data is not displayed on the template.

Here is the **Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataserviceService {
    result:any; 
    constructor(private http:Http) { }
    getusers()
       {
           return this.http.get('/users').map( result => this.result = result.json());
       }
    }
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataserviceService } from './dataservice.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    users : Array<any> = [];
    constructor(private dataserv : DataserviceService)
     {
        this.dataserv.getusers().subscribe(function(result)
         {
            this.users = result;
            console.log(result);//result is rightly displayed on the console.
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the **template**

```
<div *ngIf="users">
  <h2>Results </h2>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The tags you apply on your question should only be those related to what the question is about. Just because you are using "mean stack" does not mean you tag your question with every technology in the stack. This is an "angular" question and is not about any other component, so that is the only tag required. That's what you do here.

Answer (score 1):

Your users array is empty when template is rendered. You should read something about change detection, and change detection strategy, zones, ... But if you use rXjs Subject/BehaviorSubject and observable data would be rendered, component:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataserviceService } from './dataservice.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    private usersSubj = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);
    users : Observable<Array<any>> = this.usersSubj.Observable();
    constructor(private dataserv : DataserviceService)
     {
        this.dataserv.getusers().subscribe(function(result)
         {
            this.usersSubj.next(result);
            console.log(result);//result is rightly displayed on the console.
        });
    }
}
```

and template:

```
<div *ngIf="users">
  <h2>Results </h2>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users | async">{{ user.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Your service could also return observable, so you could subscribe users to service directy, ...

Comment: I have made changes like you said and it throws me this error " Module '"G://MEAN1/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'. "

Comment: sorry, syntax error, it should be: import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

Comment: And now it says "app.component.ts (13,53): Property 'Observable' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<any[]>'."

Comment: users : Observable<Array<any>> = this.usersSubj.asObservable();

Comment: And now it throws this "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next "

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

use ***ngIf="users.length > 0"** instead of ***ngIf="users"**

```
<div *ngIf="users.length > 0">
  <h2>Results </h2>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```